# Within a Julia script, can you tell whether the script has been imported or executed directly?

Tags: julia

A common convention in python is to structure the main functionality of a script as follows, so it can be both run as a script directly or imported without executing `main()` at the time of import:

```
def main():
    do_stuff()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Is there a similar variable that gets set in Julia, so that the script can be aware of whether it was imported using `require("script.jl"`) or executed directly?

For example, say I have two scripts, `a.jl` and `b.jl`, along with a `magic_function()` that behaves as follows:

**a.jl**:

```
println("Did we execute a.jl directly? ", magic_function())
```

**b.jl**:

```
require("a.jl")
```

Executing the following commands results in ...

```
> julia a.jl
Did we execute a.jl directly? true
> julia b.jl
Did we execute a.jl directly? false
```

Does a function like `magic_function()` exist in the current distribution of Julia?

Answer (score 12):

Official Julia doc suggests this:

```
if abspath(PROGRAM_FILE) == @__FILE__

    # do something only this file is executed. 
    do_something()

end
```

The do_something function is only executed when the code is executed, not when the code is imported from other codes.

Ref:"How do I check if the current file is being run as the main script?"
https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/faq/#How-do-I-check-if-the-current-file-is-being-run-as-the-main-script?-1

Comment: Not quite.  `PROGRAM_FILE` is `""` at the default REPL, and all strings contain `""`.  There may be other path-based false-positives, too.

Comment: This doesn’t work: when I run `./script.jl`, `@__FILE__` is `/home/me/script.jl` and `PROGRAM_FILE` is `./script.jl`. The latter is not contained in the former, so the condition is false. @oyd11’s solution above always works.

Comment: In its current form and as of 2020-2021, I think this should be the accepted answer

Answer (score 8):

While `isinteractive()` will let you discern the REPL from being run on the commandline/imported into other code, there is no way to get exactly the same functionality as Python's `if __name__ == '__main__'`.

This does not seem to be planned as a feature. See this [discussion on the mailing list](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/julia-users/ufpi8tV7sk8/discussion). (from June 2013)

Answer (score 8):

This is the best solution I have found:

```julia
module mymod
    # stuff here
end

if length(ARGS)>0 && ARGS[1] == "--run"
    using mymod
    mymod.myfunction()
end
```

Then you can import the module as normal, but you can invoke the executable like behaviour from the command line like this:

```
julia mycode.jl --run
```

The if statement could even be shortened to this if you have no other arguments to pass to the script:

```julia
if ARGS == ["--run"]
    # etc...
end
```

Comment: What if I write a script `abc.jl` that imports your `mycode.jl` and do `julia abc.jl`, then your your `mycode.jl` will still think it's being run directly, which is not true. If so, then your answer is not equivalent to Python's approach.

Answer (score 6):

I use

```
if ""!=PROGRAM_FILE && realpath(@__FILE__) == realpath(PROGRAM_FILE)
```

I've seem a similar solution was voted down above, I'd like to know what's wrong with that, I'm using this both for a few unit-tests and some modules that are also commandline `chmod 755` utils

(just added the `""!=PROGRAM_FILE` for the 'REPL include' case, becoming a bit of a mouthful)

Answer (score 3):

You want the `isinteractive()` function. Try it out in the REPL, the compare its result with the result of calling it from a script like in this BASH one-liner: `julia -e "println(isinteractive())"`.

Comment: Is that the same thing, though?  `julia test.jl` where the script is simply `println(isinteractive())` will print `false`, whereas `python test.py` / `print __name__ == '__main__'` will print `True`.

Comment: This isn't quite what I need: isinteractive() tests whether it's executed from the REPL or from running julia my_script.jl, not I ran julia my_script.jl or julia script_that_requires_my_script.jl. Updating the question for clarity.