# What does `abspath(PROGRAM_FILE) == @__FILE__` do?

Tags: julia

Given this code:

```
function main()
    println("hello")
end

if abspath(PROGRAM_FILE) == @__FILE__
    main()
end
```

What does the last part do, and how does it work? Where are those variables defined?

Comment: Cross-posting a link to the reverse question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/14462557/1225607

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`PROGRAM_FILE` is a global constant defined as the string containing the script name passed to the executing Julia process from the command line (the first element of the `argv` in C terms, I think).

`@__FILE__` is a macro expanding to the name of the file it is expanded in.

The combination shown is the Julia variant of Python's `if __name__ == '__main__'`: when the file is run as a script, `PROGRAM_FILE` will contain the script name, equal to the current file, and `main` will be called.  When the file is included or imported from somewhere else, `PROGRAM_FILE` will contain the name of whatever script used the current file, and differ from the current file name.